# How can I update a value in a view in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, object, yii, return-value

Hi I have a question about yii Framework.I want to update a value in view.php and I use the following code in BilgiformuController

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->okunma=1;
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),

        ));
    }
```

But the code, I used not working.How can I update "okunma" value in actionView.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
    $this->loadModel($id)->okunma=1;
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),

    ));
```

retrieves the model (object), changes the `okunma` property and throws it away (because the return value of `loadModel()` call is not being stored anywhere) and the other `loadModel()` call simply retrieves the model again.

I think what you meant was:

```
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $model->okunma=1;
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
```

this way the retrieved object is stored in a variable, allowing you to modify it and pass it to `render()` once modified.

And if you want this change to propagate to database as well, you need to `save()` the model:

```
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $model->okunma=1;
    $model->save();
```

Comment: @MahmutAydın You're welcome. I also suggest you to find some good book with basics of PHP, about variables, return values etc., you need to study more :)

Comment: ooops.The code display in view but it is not update in database.

Comment: @MahmutAydın: Yes, for that you need to `save()` it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't perform update operation in views. I think you want to set model attribute and show this on view - then solution presented by @Liho is correct. If you want to save data to DB, you should assing $_POST attributes to your model:

```
$model = $this->loadModel($id);
$model->okunma=1;
if(isset($_POST['yourModelName'))
{
    $model->attributes = $_POST['yourModelName']);
    if($model->validate())
    {
       $model->save(false);
       // other operations, eg. redirect
    }
}
$this->render('view',array(
    'model' => $model,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = YourModel::model()->findByPk($id);
$model->okunma=1;
$model->save(false);
$this->render('view',array(
    'model' => $model,
));
```